# Proper power button action handling in a game

Tags: android, android-screen

I'm working on a problem with the power button pressed when my game is open. As my log says, after the screen is locked a series of different `Activity` lifecycle callbacks are called and the same happens when the screen is unlocked. I'm starting the background music playback in `onResume()`, so how can I make sure that I don't play music while the screen is locked? I've learned about `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` broadcasts, but AFAIK it's not recommended to listen for those events. Is there any elegant workaround on this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you pause it in onPause method, you should have the effect you desire, no?

Answer (score -1):

Use `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` ... it is what you want.